"cannot import name 'Literal' from 'statsmodels.compat.python' " trying from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, kpss
I am trying to import the following:
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, kpss

and I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'statsmodels.compat.python'

Does anybody know what is it due to?

Mine works, with statsmodels version 0.14.1, can you provide yours?
